# Is there way to restrict resource access by other 'Owners' in the same Azure Subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-rbac

There are a bunch of people in a Security Group and the Group itself is owner of the subscription. So all the members of the group will obviously have full access to all the resources under the subscription. Removing the people from the SG is a different matter altogether and that is not feasible. Is there any other way I can at least protect the resources I create in that none else in the group should be able to modify my resources? I am not referring to a specific type of resources , but asking in general, it could be a Azure Data Factory, Azure SQL Server etc. anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [deny assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/deny-assignments) in Azure, deny assignments block users from performing specific Azure resource actions even if a role assignment grants them access.

But the deny assignments are created and managed by Azure. Azure Blueprints and Azure managed apps are the only way that deny assignments can be created. You can't directly create your own deny assignments.

---

From the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10855878-deny-access-control-in-the-rbac), Microsoft is working on the custom deny definition which will help to meet your requirement.

[image]